# Springboot Security+JWT with JPA having Error with unknown error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, jwt

I gave up to fixing security source code..
On security services(SecurityConfig,ResourceServerConfig,AuthorizationServerConfig)
 
of configurations are all passed. But not able to start server.

I was hope to fix it.

```
2018-06-12 18:27:11.714  INFO 7956 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
SecurityConfig configureGlobal config start
SecurityConfig configureGlobal config end
AuthorizationServerConfig AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer config start
AuthorizationServerConfig AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer config end
2018-06-12 18:27:12.356  INFO 7956 --- [           main] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize],methods=[POST],params=[user_oauth_approval]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.View org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.approveOrDeny(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ?>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal)
2018-06-12 18:27:12.357  INFO 7956 --- [           main] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.authorize(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal)
2018-06-12 18:27:12.359  INFO 7956 --- [           main] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2018-06-12 18:27:12.359  INFO 7956 --- [           main] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
2018-06-12 18:27:12.360  INFO 7956 --- [           main] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/check_token]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ?> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.CheckTokenEndpoint.checkToken(java.lang.String)
2018-06-12 18:27:12.360  INFO 7956 --- [           main] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/confirm_access]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.WhitelabelApprovalEndpoint.getAccessConfirmation(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception
2018-06-12 18:27:12.361  INFO 7956 --- [           main] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/oauth/error]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.WhitelabelErrorEndpoint.handleError(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
AuthorizationServerConfig ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer config start
AuthorizationServerConfig ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer config end
AuthorizationServerConfig AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer config start
AuthorizationServerConfig AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer config end
ResourceServerConfig ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config start
ResourceServerConfig ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config end
ResourceServerConfig HttpSecurity config start
ResourceServerConfig HttpSecurity config end
SecurityConfig AuthenticationManagerBuilder config start
SecurityConfig AuthenticationManagerBuilder config end
SecurityConfig HttpSecurity config start
SecurityConfig HttpSecurity config end
2018-06-12 18:27:12.565  WARN 7956 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(Lorg/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder;)V
2018-06-12 18:27:12.566  INFO 7956 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-06-12 18:27:12.568  INFO 7956 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-06-12 18:27:12.582  INFO 7956 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-06-12 18:27:12.591 ERROR 7956 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(Lorg/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at kr.avansoft.demo.TokenServerTestV3Application.main(TokenServerTestV3Application.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(Lorg/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(Lorg/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder;)V
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.userdetails.AbstractDaoAuthenticationConfigurer.passwordEncoder(AbstractDaoAuthenticationConfigurer.java:72)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$DefaultPasswordEncoderAuthenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:573)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.userDetailsService(HttpSecurity.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.init(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.java:141)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.init(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:371)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:325)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:292)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bd8e9a1.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$2(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bd8e9a1$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2e84430f.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bd8e9a1.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

how can i fix it? and which things i missed?
if i was then please teach for me

if need some codes then i'll upload that. thank you.

---

I used Gradle. and Here have my gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'

group = 'GROUP_NAME'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')

    compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.1.3.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:4.1.3.RELEASE')

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.0.2.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.3.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:1.0.9.RELEASE')

    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.3.0.Final')

    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    runtime('com.h2database:h2:1.4.197')

    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: Such errors are normally caused by JAR file conflicts. If this is a Maven project then post your POM.

Comment: @AlanHay I used Gradle. so i added that. sorry for late..